# Unable to install ubuntu 15.04 64 bit OS

Tags: system-installation, 15.04, 64-bit

When I boot from my pendrive and go into boot options under my pendrive, which has Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit), it says 'insecure boot' and does not boot into pendrive.

Any solutions for this?

I have 8GB of RAM and I want to install the latest version of 64 bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Your USB drive seems to not be properly configured.

Assuming you are running a current Ubuntu system:

1. Open built-in <kbd>Disks</kbd> tool and click <kbd>☰</kbd> (right top corner) and select <kbd>Restore Disk Image</kbd>
2. Choose the Ubuntu 15.04 ISO image, select the USB drive to write it to and start the process
3. Reboot the computer and select the <kbd>UEFI - USB - drive entry</kbd> from BIOS menu to boot from

Answer (score -1):

Your system uefi firmware aparently does not allow booting untrusted (which is cryptographically unsigned) operating systems. See if you can access the firmware (usually by pressing a brand/model specific key during the early boot) and change the setting.

Comment: Unless he has a very limited system that allows booting only vendor-provided kernel (never heard of those actually) this is not a case. Ubuntu kernel, by default, is signed with a valid and registered sign and can boot on SecureBoot systems.